# Degree $4$ curves on K3 double covers of Del-Pezzo surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, curves-and-surfaces, k3-surfaces

Let $S$ be a smooth del-Pezzo surface and $\pi : X \longrightarrow S$ be the double cover of $S$ ramified in a smooth section of $-2K_S$. Going through the classification of del-Pezzo surfaces, one can see that there is always a curve (not necessarily rational) $C \subset X$ such that $-\pi^*K_S.C =4$. If $S$ has a line with respect to $-K_S$ (meaning a curve $L$ such that $L.L = -1$ and $-K_S.L = 1$), then it is obvious, just take the pull back of a curve in $|2L|$.

From the classification of del Pezzo surfaces, one sees that the only del-Pezzo surfaces which don't have lines with respect to $-K_S$ are $\mathbb{P}^2$ and $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$. In the latter case, a ruling (in any direction) has $2$ points of intersection with $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(2) \boxtimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(2)$, hence the pull back of such a ruling is okay.

<s>In the case of $\mathbb{P}^2$, there is somehting to say. Let $x$ be an inflection point of the sextic giving the ramification locus and $L$ be the tangent to the sextic at $x$. If I am not mistaken, the pull-back $\pi^*L$ splits into two curves, say $C_1$ and $C_2$, and we have $-\pi^*K_{\mathbb{P}^2}.C_1 = 4$, while $-\pi^*K_{\mathbb{P}^2}.C_2 = 8$. So the curve $C_1$ satisfies the hypothesis $-\pi^*K_S.C =4$.</s>

**Edit** : As noticed by Sasha in the comments, in the case of $\mathbb{P}^2$, the projection formula shows that for any curve $C \subset X$, the intersection number $- \pi^*K_{\mathbb{P}^2}.C = -K_{\mathbb{P}^2}.\pi(C)$ is divisible by $3$. So in the case of $\mathbb{P}^2$ it seems there is no curve $C \subset X$ such that $-\pi^*K_S.C =4$.

I was wondering if there was a more uniform way to get the existence of a curve $C \subset X$ such that $-\pi^*K_S.C =4$ (except in the case of $\mathbb{P}^2$) ? Perhaps using the lattice theory associated to curves on K3 surfaces with involution?

Comment: The canonical class of $\mathbb{P}^2$ is divisible by 3, so its intersection with any curve is divisible by 3 as well.